# How do I make my music player treat my Mass Storage Class mp3 player and its MicroSD card as a single player?

Tags: sd-card, mp3-player

Specifically, I'm using Banshee on linux for my music player, and my mp3 player is a Sansa Clip+, but I wanted to keep the question general for all MSC devices.

I added a `.is_audio_player` file to both the Clip+ and its card, so now they both show up in Banshee. But I want to be able to just sync my library with it, instead of trying to figure out how much to drag to each half. Is there a way to do this, or am I out of luck?

Edit: I don't plan on switching cards in and out. I'm using the MicroSD card solely to increase the capacity of my Clip+, not because it is removable.

Comment: the hardware is two separate devices, shows up as two separate filesystems, so either you get to manage them separately or some software makes those decisions for you.  perhaps badly -- what if you had 3 SD cards and wanted to swap between them?  it's not that what you want is impossible, it's that it's very difficult to make such behavior intelligent, automatic *and* useful.

Comment: Fair enough, but I'd be happy with a solution that assumes that I'd NEVER switch the cards. I don't plan on it, and if I ever do, I'd be ok with resyncing my entire library to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround for now is to make a smart playlist to hold "the first 7.5Gb" of my music. I drag this playlist to the player, then I drag the rest of my music (starting after the last song in the smart playlist) to the microSD card.

It's still pretty cumbersome, so if anyone has a better solution (one that allows me to automatically sync), please post it!